# Setting up onedark as a colorscheme in Vim?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I'm trying to set up my color scheme on vim using [onedark](https://github.com/joshdick/onedark.vim)

I've cloned the repository and ran the following commands:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/joshdick/onedark.vim.git ~/onedark
$ cd ~/onedark
$ mkdir ~/.vim/colors
$ cp colors/onedark.vim ~/.vim/colors/
$ cp autoload/onedark.vim ~/.vim/autoload/
```

My `.vimrc` contains a few settings and I added

```
syntax on
colorscheme onedark
```

But my editor still shows like this:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

You need to put this to your vimrc:

```
" Turns on syntax highlighting
syntax on

if has('termguicolors')
    " Turns on true terminal colors
    let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
    let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"

    " Turns on 24-bit RGB color support
    set termguicolors

    " Defines how many colors should be used. (maximum: 256, minimum: 0)
    set t_Co=256
endif

set background=dark
colorscheme onedark
```

However, if you want Color scheme work well you have to install any syntax highlighter, such as (most popular):

1. [nvim-treesitter](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter) for NeoVim
2. [vim-polyglot](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot) for Vim.
3. Or, you can configure [tree-sitter](https://github.com/tree-sitter) manually for Vim.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Vim in a terminal, you will also have to install the appropriate color scheme for your terminal. For example, if you use iTerm then you will have to download and install the [One Dark.itermcolors](https://github.com/joshdick/onedark.vim/blob/master/term/One%20Dark.itermcolors) color scheme.

I advice you to read the [Troubleshooting](https://github.com/joshdick/onedark.vim#troubleshooting) section, as there may be other issues with your setup.